# peatio: what is default password for database.yml?

Tags: ruby

I just tried to install peatio and I see that password is empty in peatio/config/database.yml

what should be written there? 
here is screenshot: http://s14.postimg.org/4ijmxjwtt/untitled.png

here is my error from terminal when I tried to start server:

> bundle exec rails server
>
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (): did
>   not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 6 column 3
>   (Psych::SyntaxError)

edited, here is full error:

> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in`parse'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:21:i
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:17:i
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro/railtie
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/applic
>           from /peatio/config/application.rb:16:in`'
>           from /peatio/config/application.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/comman
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/comman
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/comman
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/comman
>           from bin/rails:4:in`require'
>           from bin/rails:4:in `'

Comment: You'll need to know the database for the mysql database's "root" user.  Do you remember choosing a password during mysql installation?

Comment: yes I do and again I get the same error. I wrote password but no result. should I restart something? I don't know how to restart ruby... here is screenshot of the whole error: http://s13.postimg.org/etpqtjp7b/untitled.png

Comment: That error seems to indicate a syntax error in the configuration file.

Comment: which one you think? config.log in ruby is too long, here is the list of files in peatio config folder: http://s28.postimg.org/z2sowc7nh/untitled2.png

Comment: The syntax error you are getting does not seem consistent with the configuration file you show.  Is it possible there is, for example, a tab in that file?   BTW: Instead of screen shots, it would be good if you edit your question and paste the config file, error messages, etc. in as text.

Answer (score 0):

Peatio default password for user admin@barong.io is Qwerty123 or Chah5YohWm