# rake db:setup always fails

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger

I am trying to install a ruby application. I am trying to use a remote db for this application. But after configuring everything, when I execute bundle exec rake db:setup, iam getting this.

```
rake aborted!
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1
/home/deploy/peatio/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:21:in `raw'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:17:in `env'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro/railtie.rb:7:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/application.rb:67:in `inherited'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/config/application.rb:15:in `<module:Peatio>'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/deploy/peatio/current/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How can I troubleshoot ?

Comment: Error points you to `config/application.rb` lines 14-15

Comment: [here is some related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283958/peatio-what-is-default-password-for-database-yml)

Comment: it looks to me like you are using the figaro gem, and it is looking for a key in is configuration `config/application.yml` and isn't finding it. I would verify that install first

Comment: Any troubleshooting checklist? I am not able to fix this yet.

Comment: Installed figaro gem. still same error.

Comment: This is my current gem list 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7e2b945ca0851826175b

Comment: Issue fixed. Problem was with the config/application.yml file. I have wrong intent in the following lines. 

<   # PUSHER_APP: 65910
<   # PUSHER_KEY: 50d404c35db92d736a57
<   # PUSHER_SECRET: 75d6e6685209cc60cc4d